# Google Custom Search box - Autocomplete

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm using the following form to implement the Google Custom Search box on my page:

```
`<form id="cse-search-box" action="http://www.myurl.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cx" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8"/>
<input type="text" name="q" etc etc.....
</form>`
```

How can I enable autocomplete in the above example?

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you check out the Google Places API https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete